# Display months and not days on xaxis in Heatmaps/Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, heatmap, highmaps

I have a heatmap, with 365 days on the xaxis and some dozen years on the yaxis. Now, I wonder if I can display the months instead of numbered days on the xaxis. In the moment it looks like this:

[image]

Clearly, the data format must then be different from this:

```
Day,Year,Value
1,1989,535
2,1989,518
3,1989,576
4,1989,542
```

However, if I change it to this:

```
Day,Year,Value
1-Jan,1989,535
2-Jan,1989,518
3-Jan,1989,576
4-Jan,1989,542
```

it really gets screwed...

I have [a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/mn68sofn/3/)

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: You need to set xAxis as datetime type and then parse your dates (in each point) to timestamp.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that hint. However, I don't understand what "parsing the dates (in each point) to timestamp" would translate to. I've changed [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/mn68sofn/5/) so that the xAxis is now in datetime, and that the "real dates" like "1 Jan", "2 Jan" are given. Could you please indicate there what I have to do? Thanks so much!

Comment: Seems that jsfiddle doens't work.

Comment: It does work. And it shows the problem that I have when changing the Day format. Instead of displaying the 365 days of the year only, it does it now for each additional year, that is: if I have ten years, it will display 10*365 on the xaxis, and these days of each year do not overlap. It's clearly a date-format problem - but I couldn't find any solution yet.

Comment: My browser crashes when Im opening your demo.

Comment: Ah, very strange. Perhaps too many data (730)? Or a setting in the code? I changed the display of the xAxis, so [here the link to the new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mn68sofn/6/). And [this image](http://i.imgur.com/y5rSFJM.png) to show how it looks like. Hope this helps.